# How Handle Output tool when file is open - Alteryx

Tags: excel, sharepoint, alteryx

The issue is, I have some files in a shared folder, i am using Alteryx to refresh and update those files daily, some people work with those files and there are the situation:

[image]

If anyone have some file open, the process cannot execute properly, and show me this message, how i can handle that?.

I have my process without Sharepoint, i tried use Sharepoint tool because i think this maybe solve this situation, but not.

So the question is, there are a option to handle that from Alteryx?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider checking before attempting to write: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Desktop-Discussions/Macro-that-checks-if-a-file-is-locked/td-p/83315